# How do I in PHP escape a string before inserting into Redis?

Tags: php, redis

What is the most secure way of escaping a string before it's inserted into a Redis database?

Answer (score 3):

Redis is binary safe both for keys and values. You do not have to escape things before putting them in Redis.